# How to Change HTTP Port in Win Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I have installed Websphere application server which is using port 80 on my system.

I also neeeded SMTP , so installed IIS on WIN2008 Server . But getting following error:

> The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/ for site 1. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are actually asking **how to change HTTP ports in IIS**.

Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager (from Administrative tools)

Connections pane:

- COMPUTER NAME

  - Sites

    - Default Web Site

Actions pane:

- Edit Site
- Bindings...

Just select the binding http->80 and edit it to meet your requirements.

Repeat for any other sites bind to port 80.

Comment: What you are describing is changing the port for the `default web site`, not the `default HTTP port in IIS`. It may still help the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I updated the answer into more generalized version. Somehow I assumed the OP only had this Default Site set up since the IIS seemed to be installed for dependent services.